# How to check if databases are consistent in pgsql replication?

Tags: postgresql

There is some tool for mysql (from percona I think) which could compare databases by making md5 sums of tables data. We used it in our mysql replication system to check if data is correctly replicated. Do you know something similar that I can use in pgsql environment ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool. It'd be fairly simple to write one using the strategy you describe, but it'd produce false negatives sometimes because of replication lag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`pg_comparator`](http://pg-comparator.projects.pgfoundry.org/pg_comparator.html).
Also older version of `pt-table-checksum` (or `mk-table-checksum`) could compare pg data - but I wouldn't recommend these old versions.